# Laravel jQuery auto complete text

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, autocomplete

I'm facing problem to display primary key from auto complete text using jQuery.

I modified the code from this source: https://www.webslesson.info/2018/06/ajax-autocomplete-textbox-in-laravel-using-jquery.html

The difference is, I tried to add primary key from auto complete text which I selected and then sent to HTML code from controller to view.

Here is my controller ( I think there is no problem here )

```php
function getProject(Request $request)
{
    if($request->get('query'))
    {
        $query = $request->get('query');
        $listProject = DB::table('project')
            ->select('PK_Project', 'projectName')
            ->where('projectName', 'ILIKE', "%{$query}%")
            ->get();

        $data = array(
            'listProject'   => $listProject,
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

And my view:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#projectname').keyup(function(){ 
            var query = $(this).val();
            var listProject = '';
            if(query != '')
            {
                var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('getProject') }}",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{query:query, _token:_token},
                    dataType:'JSON',
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#projectList').empty();
                        $('#projectList').fadeIn();  
                        $('#projectList').append(
                            '<ul class= "dropdown-menu" style= "display:block; position:relative">'
                            );
                        
                        data.listProject.forEach(element => {
                            // I can get project name list here
                            $('#projectList').append( "<li><a href='#'>" + element.projectName + "</a></li>");
                            // I can get project Primary Key list here
                            $('#pkproject').append(element.PK_Project);
                        });
                        
                        $('#projectList').append('</ul>');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    
        $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
            $('#projectname').val($(this).text()); // I can get project name that I clicked 
            $('#pkproject').val($(this).text());  // This is what I asked (how?)
            $('#projectList').fadeOut();  
        });  
    
    });
</script>
```

The second question is how to fix dropdown menu (text is outside the box)

[image: autotext example]

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a syntax error in getProject method

```
 ->where('projectName', 'ILIKE', "%{$query}%")
```

Should be

```
 ->where('projectName', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. the difference between LIKE and ILIKE is in case sensitive. LIKE is case sensitive. ILIKE isn't case sensitive.